# Can't set an arbitrary attribute in an instance of an object

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm using the pygame library, it has an object pygame.Surface() that has a bunch of methods. This is what I'm trying to do:

```
my_surface = pygame.Surface((5,5)) #the object requires a size to instantiate
my_surface.coords = (10,10)
```

But it throws me this error:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
AttributeError: 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute 'coords'
```

same things happen if I use

```
setattr(my_surface, 'coords', (10,10))
```

instead of

```
my_surface.coords = (10,10)
```

BUT if I make my own class

```
class MyClass():
    pass

instance = MyClass()
instance.coords = (10,10)
```

it works like a charm.

I've read that it has something to do with not having a __dict__ on every instance of an object (though it was about the default python object()) which would cause objects to use too much memory, and indeed when I do

```
my_surface.__dict__ #this is a pygame.Surface() object
```

it throws

```
AttributeError: 'pygame.Surface' object has no attribute '__dict__'
```

while

```
instance.__dict__ #this is a MyClass() object
```

returns

```
{}
```

Is there any way I can modify this particular instance to accept arbitrary attributes? Currently the only workaround I can think of is to create a child class for pygame.Surface() and give it a __dict__, but obviously it's rather confusing to have to choose in advance whether or not I'll need to add arbitrary attributes for every instance of a Surface(), and and instantiating every Surface with a __dict__ defeats the whole purpose of it having no __dict__ in the first place.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I don't think there's a better way than subclassing `Surface` if you *really* need to be able to assign arbitrary attributes to an instance. The subclass can be empty if you don't need to add any other features (the instance `__dict__` will be created automatically).

```
class MySurface(pygame.Surface):
    pass
```

However, I'm not sure you really need that ability.

A better design is generally to encapsulate the `Surface` object and whatever other data you have as attributes of some other object type. In Pygame you'll often use a subclass of `pygame.sprite.Sprite` to bundle a `Surface` (as the `image` attribute) with coordinates (as part of the `rect` attribute). If you have any other data you need to bundle, the `Sprite` can take it too. `Sprite` instances have a `__dict__` by default, even if you don't write your own subclass.

Comment: Okay I'm fucking stupid, I stumbled upon your solution while researching to explain my problem thoroughly, but then I discovered that the reason objects didn't accept new attributes was the lack of a `__dict__ `, so I went into the console and tried `pygame.Surface().__dict__ `, and it returned something, so I thought that since it did have a dict it should accept new attributes. Only after thirty minutes did I realize that it didn't because instances didn't have a `__dict__`, and at that point I had forgotten I had my answer already so I still posted. Thank you very much nonetheless.

Comment: @Kyll I am terribly sorry but I am unable to find the edit button on the comment, although I see a little pen next to yours that says it was edited so I understand it is possible, I just do not see it. Would you mind sharing a screenshot of where I should look?

edit: apparently I can edit this one, maybe I can't edit comments after they've been replied to?